# How can I verify presence of text under a specific <DIV> tag using Selenium WebDriver (java) and Chrome?

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Background: I'm using Selenium WebDriver in Java and using Google Chrome as my browser.

So I'm not too sure of this one. I know how to figure out if specific text is present on the page, however what if there were more than one instance of the text that I want to find? For instance, if the word "Hello" is on the top of the page, and the word "Hello" also appears upon expanding a  element, how would I verify that the second "Hello" is there without completely specifying its xpath?

For example:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, WAIT_TIME);
foundElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + expectedText + "')]")));
```

...this will obtain the FIRST instance of the text I'm looking for...but what if I'm looking for another specific instance (3rd, 4th)?

Trying to AVOID using something like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, WAIT_TIME);
foundElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//*[contains(text(),'" + expectedText + "')])[2]")));
```

Preferably I would like to try to specify the  element it's under. Any ideas folks?

I'm not MAJORLY familiar with xpath...but suppose I wanted to do something LIKE this (I already know this is invalid/doesn't work):

```
WebElement foundElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"elementID\"]/[contains(text(),'" + text + "')]")));
```

I hope that makes sense! Please let me know if any clarification is needed.

**Small Update:**

I tried this to no avail:

```
WebElement foundElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"elementID\"]/*/[contains(text(),'" + text + "')]")));
```

Here is the path that contains the text I'm trying to find:

```
//*[@id="Highchart_chart_property_hot_alerts"]/div[1]/div[1]
```

It is the SECOND occurrence of the text on the page. A possibly acceptable way of finding if it's there is checking that BOTH of the texts are present as opposed to JUST the second one. So I might attempt that approach. Any other insight still welcome.

Comment: `By.xpath("//*[@id='elementID']/*[contains(text(),'" + text + "')]")` looks perfectly valid, why wouldn't it work?

Comment: I think perhaps because the text I'm looking for is a little bit deeper. I received a TimeoutException. My issue is that I'm trying to keep it as generic as possible so many situations can fit. Here's the full xpath of the text I'm trying to find: 

//*[@id="elementID"]/div[1]/div[1]

Ideally I want to avoid using anything further than the elementID.

Comment: can you post sample html of elements you are interested in finding?

Comment: @nilesh I updated the question accordingly. Does that help? Thanks to both of you for taking the time to look into my issue!

Comment: I am not looking for xpath. I am looking for html. Is the xpath you posted for the second instance of "Hello"? Are you able to find the first "Hello" instance fine?

Comment: That is a correct assumption. My apologies for not being clearer. Looks like t0mppa gave me a perfect solution, so that won't be necessary. Once again, thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your base HTML is:

```
<table id='bar'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <div class="foo">hello</div>
        <div>world</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You need to always specify the type of tag to find in xpath. So using `//table/tr/td/div/[@class='foo']` won't work. Also a `/*/` is not very useful, since `//` means "skip any number of children and their children and so on". Thus you'd want: `//table[@id='bar']//div[@class='foo']`

So in regards to your question, the solution appears to be:

```
By locator = By.xpath("//*[@id='Highchart_chart_property_hot_alerts']//div[contains(text(),'" + text + "')]");
WebElement foundElement = waitAndFindElement(locator);

private WebElement waitAndFindElement(By locator) {
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, WAIT_TIME);
  return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator)));
}
```

Comment: PERFECT! Clear and concise explanation. Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, I think .//div[text()[contains('text')]] also might work in some cases where the above answer wont.

Comment: Possible, but he said he has multiple instances of hello's and only wants a specific one, so yours would catch any div with text on it and thus might match one of them or all of them for instance. Hard to say without seeing the actual HTML source.

Answer (score 0):

Approach:

By Getting the Index:

CSS Selector of div that contains the Text "Hello":css=div:contains("Hello")

```
List<WebElement> texts = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div:contains('Hello')"));

if(texts.get(2).getText().equals("hello")

    // Then Second Element that contains the Text Hello is present.

else 

    // Not Present.
```